# I can registration user without login using wp_insert_user?

Tags: wordpress

I use wp_insert_user to add a user, but there you need to have a username and password, and I only need mail without a username and password. Just use this function, because there is not a bad functionality, which I then need.

```
  $user_company = $array_jsons['company'];
  $user_email = $array_jsons['email'];
  $role = $array_jsons['role'];
  $info = array(
    'user_login'  =>  '', // how i do without login 
    'user__pass'  =>  '', // how i do without login 
    'user_company' => $user_company,
    'user_email' => $user_email,
    'display_name' => $user_email,
    'role' => $role
 );
  $result = wp_insert_user( $info );
  if(is_wp_error( $result)) {
    echo $result->get_error_message();
  } else {
    echo "Added user {$result}";
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add the emails as username and password, because username and password are the mandatory fields

```
$user_company = $array_jsons['company'];
  $user_email = $array_jsons['email'];
  $role = $array_jsons['role'];
  $info = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $user_email, // how i do without login 
    'user__pass'  =>  $user_email, // how i do without login 
    'user_company' => $user_company,
    'user_email' => $user_email,
    'display_name' => $user_email,
    'role' => $role
 );
  $result = wp_insert_user( $info );
  if(is_wp_error( $result)) {
    echo $result->get_error_message();
  } else {
    echo "Added user {$result}";
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I did it, but then he displays a mistake then that supposedly such a user with such a name suicide, but we understand that he means that email that we put in place of the login, but others will be confused

Comment: But according to WordPress, the username is mandatory but for the display_name you can actually get the name from the email of the user. for example "john@gmail.com" is the email then you can get the name "john" from email and set that to display_name

Comment: I do not want to write a function that takes entries to a certain symbol(((

Comment: And if the mail will be the same before @?

Comment: Why would you approve this? I know it works, but you should NEVER add a password that's the same as email, hat's the first thing someone or a bot will try when bruteforcing your account.